# How to speed up mySql query with multiple join

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have performance issue with following query, it's working fine with small data but when large data it's taking approx 8 to 10 sec. so can anyone help me on this?

```
SELECT DISTINCT flt.filter_id, fltd.name, fltd.description, fltd.seo,
flt.filter_group_id
FROM filter AS flt
LEFT JOIN filter_description AS fltd ON flt.filter_id = fltd.filter_id
LEFT JOIN product_filter AS pf ON flt.filter_id = pf.filter_id
LEFT JOIN product AS p ON p.product_id = pf.product_id
WHERE p.status =1 AND p.quantity >0 AND flt.filter_group_id IN (1, 2, 5, 8, 11 )
GROUP BY flt.filter_id
ORDER BY fltd.name ASC
```

My Database table approx size:
product : 50000
product_filter : 600000
filter : 5000
filter_description: 5000

Filter used as follows:

Product 1 => (Color : Green) (Size: 10,20) (Fabric: Cotton)

Product 2 => (Color : Red) (Size: 20,40) (Fabric: Cotton)

Product 2 => (Color : Yellow) (Size: 20) (Fabric: Silk, Cotton)

I want result as follows:

Color: Green, Red, Yellow

Size: 10, 20, 40

Fabric: Cotton, Silk

I think it's taking much time due to it's search all filter again and again for each products.

so anyone can help me on this get fastest results?

filter_group_id, filter_id, product_id, status and quantity are indexed

Comment: Can you post your current indexes on tables?

Comment: You have a GROUP BY clause, but no aggregating functions. Why? Also, your final join renders as an inner join, so you might as well write it that way.

Comment: filter_group_id, filter_id, product_id, status and quantity are indexed

Comment: I had remove group by filter_id but keep DISTINCT because this query will return all product filters but i want only 1 result for each filter name... I want to make left side filters like http://www.snapdeal.com/products/men-apparel-jeans?sort=plrty you can see brand, size etc. as filter